# Nesting filters is not wokring

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to filter based on contractTypeId which is present in existingContracttypes.

First Image  - 0th Index value

Second Image  - 1st index value
[![ 0 index ][1]][1]

[![1 index][2]][2]

```
selectedContractTypeIds=[1,2,3];
```

This value is obtained from multiselect dropdown which corresponds to the contracttypeId values.

```
 this.searchClauseList=  this.searchClauseList.filter((x) => x.existingContractTypes.filter((y) => selectedContractTypeIds.indexOf(y.contractTypeId) >-1) );
```

This above code doesn't work.Can anyone help me with this code

Suppose if the

```
selectedContractTypeIds=[1,2,5,6]
```

sample output for the above contractIds is

```
[{
..
..
..
existingcontractTypes:[
     { contractTypeId:2, contractTypeName:"MSA"....}
]
..
..
},
{
 ..
 ..
 ..
 existingcontractTypes:[
         { contractTypeId:2, contractTypeName:"MSA"....}
]
```

]

I hope this sample helps u understand my question
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPKQV.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhFwj.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is pretty hard to understand, please be more precise and make it easy for us to understand what you want.

```
this.searchClauseList = this.searchClauseList.filter(
  x => x.existingContractTypes.filter(
    y => selectedContractTypeIds.indexOf(y.contractTypeId) > -1
  )
)
```

Here is what is going on in this code: you `filter` the `searchClauseList` object using the function that you pass to `filter`. `filter` will leave those and only those values of `searchClauseList` for which the function returns `true` (non-boolean values are converted to boolean, so if function returns `false`, `undefined`, `null`, `0` or `''` for some element, this element will be *excluded* from the array, if it returns anything else, it will be *included*). In your case this function return the result of another `filter`, and the result of another `filter`. `filter` always returns an array (which may be empty or not) and an array is a truthy value, so the outer `filter` will just *include* every element of `searchClauseList` because your function returns a truthy value for any element of `searchClauseList`, this is why it doesn't work.

To make it work, think about what you need: you need to `filter` your `searchClauseList` array to include *only* elements where `some` object in an array `element.existingContractTypes` is in `selectedContractTypeIds`. So you need to use `some` function inside, not `filter`:

```
this.searchClauseList.filter(
  x => x.existingContractTypes.some(
    y => selectedContractTypeIds.indexOf(y.contractTypeId) > -1
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but your solution didn't work for me.

Comment: @mohammedfahimullah maybe because I forgot to add `> -1` in the second code snippet, I'll update the answer

Comment: You guys both saved me today.keep up your good work.

Answer (score 1):

filter() methods of an array require that an item that you iterate will return a boolean.
You inner filter contains a call to indexOf() > -1, which will result in a boolean, but the outer does not.
My guess for your outer filter() call is that you meant to check if there are any items in the array at all (.lenght > 0).

Not sure if I interpret your question properly, but I've tried to simulate your situation in code and get the same issue with your current filtering + I fixed it when I applied the suggestion I made. [Example online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=12&pln=26&pc=12#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUF60AOATgJYBuYS80RFAtgIzQC8aAJosMXkkQPYB2ALmgByavHrCANNHgAPIsiJ8A5gGF%20SAmGBJYATzyIhAbVTANWnfsMBJFkLoBfALqOA3DnzEyFKrQBMTKzsnNz8QqIBUjLyiirqfJraugZG0KbmiZYptvbQTq4emLiEpOSUYjQAzEGobBAcRFy8giKVVdFyCtzxFsnWaRl9Vql2Qv4u7p6lPhW0ACy19Y3N4W0LnbE9asM5g2a7A2PQVZNFJd7lfuIArEshTWGtkeLzm91KO1n9qRAmB98RrkhPMztNLr5KgA2e4NUItCKVN7SLpxL5JIH7TIYvbHG5g7DFfAAVwARiAiMBoBB4GACMAABaqcDEmkAGW6QWMSAZCgAdJU6NIefzKv5hbyIALaFUJaKFnKpZUborpeIoc4itMyRSqQRiXwABQASjQnlwmWQ1PgIHgOngLASOKOLBgzGMQvFVU15ugIqlNLpjOZYFZ8A5VuYfslfMD9KZLPZ3T5ADMiCAKARDb7cIbZKbGAA%20aCyPmo7ZO7IDKVpjPwLM53DQQ16AvFmm2%202Ow6jV0CvhsWQAeRTLb52KrvdNhYAtHRG8a%20baVDzoMWAAy%2043naCOLB7wmWlAUSPQPjwADucEQSBNWswlp4tqXPGUhuMfM-J6Qsdp8ZDYYRkgzhLvAK4MtIwgAELwCmPAEPAwjblg358vqRrIQ%20-AQE%208Avm%20H5fjev5BgmoZJsgIHLsoPKQQAgimmZIW4QA)

Comment: Thanks for your solution.It works perfectly.Can u explain your code.

Comment: Alex Chashin explained it very well.
You called filter(), using the result of another filter() call:
itemsX.filter(x => itemsY.filter(y => true));

* the return value of the call items.Y.filter() is an array
* an array converts to boolean "true" (even if it's empty)
* that true value is then used as the return value of your x.filter(), like this:

itemsX.filter(x => true);

* This will always return all items that are in itemsX

The solution for you is to check if itemsY.filter() actually left any items in the array:

itemsX.filter(x => itemsY.filter(y => true).length > 0);